# send a Nested array json from symfony2 to angular2

Tags: php, json, symfony

i have an sql table called "planning" whchi contain id_place , id_event , date_event. i wrote this code with symfony2 to send the dates of an event grouped by place.

```
$query2 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
 $query2->select("p.libPlace ,  p.idPlace ")
        ->from('AppBundle:Place', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Planning', 'pl', 'WITH', 'pl.idPlace = p.idPlace')
        ->where('pl.idCevent = :id')

        ->setParameter('id', $idEvent)
        ->groupBy('p.idPlace');
$q2 = $query2->getQuery();
$places = $q2->getResult();

$taille = sizeof($places);   

 $j=0; $a=array();
for ($i=0; $i<= $taille-1; $i++)
{ 

$query4 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$query4->select(" z.dateEventPlace dateEventPlace")
        ->from('AppBundle:Planning', 'z')
        ->where('z.idCevent = :id')
        ->andWhere('z.idPlace = :idp')
        ->setParameter('id', $idEvent)
        ->setParameter('idp', $places[$i]['idPlace'])
        ->orderBy('dateEventPlace', 'ASC');
$q4 = $query4->getQuery();
$planning = $q4->getResult();

$p[$j]=$places[$i];
$j++;
$p[$j]=$planning;
$j++;

}return array('places' =>  $p);
```

i got this json response :

```
places":[
{"libPlace":"Le Colis\u00e9e","idPlace":1},
[{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-19T08:09:00+0000"},{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-19T14:19:00+0000"},{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-24T14:08:00+0000"}],
{"libPlace":"ABC","idPlace":2},
[{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-22T14:10:00+0000"},{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-24T16:20:00+0000"}]
]
```

and i want to get something like this:

```
places":[
{
"libPlace":"Le Colis\u00e9e","idPlace":1,"times":[
{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-19T08:09:00+0000"},{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-19T14:19:00+0000"}]
},
{
"libPlace":"ABC","idPlace":2,"times":[ 
{"dateEventPlace":"2017-03-22T14:10:00+0000"}]
}
]
```

any solution pls??

Comment: can you paste a var dump of `$planning` and `$p`

Comment: 0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'libPlace' => string 'Le Colisée' (length=11)
      'idPlace' => int 1
      'dateEventPlace' => 
        object(DateTime)[430]
          public 'date' => string '2017-03-19 14:19:00.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

Comment: 1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'dateEventPlace' => 
            object(DateTime)[447]
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'dateEventPlace' => 
            object(DateTime)[441]
              ...
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'dateEventPlace' => 
            object(DateTime)[463]
              ...

Comment: 2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'libPlace' => string 'Le Colisée' (length=11)
      'idPlace' => int 1
      'dateEventPlace' => 
        object(DateTime)[423]
          public 'date' => string '2017-03-20 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)

Comment: 3 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          'dateEventPlace' => 
            object(DateTime)[436]
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          'dateEventPlace' => 
            object(DateTime)[381]
              ...
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'dateEventPlace' => 
            object(DateTime)[460]
              ...

Comment: this is what var_dump($p) give